# Lipschitz function

Tags: calculus, continuity

> A function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined to be Lipschitz if there is a constant $K>0$ such that for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ 
>   $$
> |f(a) - f(b)| \le K|a - b|
> $$
>   $(a)$ Use the mean value theorem to show that the function $f(x) = 2\sin(x)$ is Lipschitz.
>
> $(b)$ Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz. Prove that $f$ is continuous. (Hints: Use squeeze law and the epsilon-delta definition of limit.

This is how I did part (a):

$2 \sin(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, in particular on $[b,a]$ and differentiable on $(b,a)$.
By MVT, there exists $c \in (b,a)$ such that 
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b}$$
But $f'(x) = 2\cos(x)$,
therefore $f'(c) = 2\cos(c)$,
therefore 
$$
2\cos(c) = \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b} \\
|2\cos(c)| = \left|\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b}\right|
$$
But $|2\cos(c)| \le 2$,
therefore $\left|\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b}\right| \le 2$ 
i.e. $|f(a) - f(b)| \le 2|a - b|$ and $f(x)$ is Lipschitz.

Can someone please verify for me that this solution is correct and if possible, give me some pointers on how to do part $(b)$? Thanks for any help!

Comment: And if anyone can please tell me how to type maths symbols correctly that would also be a huge help. Thanks again.

Comment: I've latex-ified your question. By clicking "edit" you should be able to see the source with the latex-markup.

Comment: Thanks for that, I appreciate it!

Comment: Your answer for (a) looks fine to me. Note that your proof for (a) doesn't depend on any properties of $f$ or $f'$ except that $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is bounded. You've thus not only shown (a), but also that *every* differentiable function whose derivative is bounded is lipschitz. Which isn't all that surprising, since the very definition of lipschitz is that the differential quotient is bounded. So for differentiable functions, being lipschitz is a rather trivial concept. Its importance lies in the fact that a function which aren't differentiable can still be lipschitz.

Answer (score 2):

For every $x_0,h\in\mathbb{R}$, $|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)|\leq K|x_0+h-x_0|=K|h|\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof for part (a) is correct. Note that the only thing you needed for the proof was that $f'(c)$ was bounded. In (exactly) the same manner you can show that if the derivative of a function $f$ is bounded then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

For part (b) note that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq K|x-x_0|\lt K\delta$ for all $x$ with $|x-x_0|\lt\delta$. Now given $\epsilon\gt0$ can we find (choose) a $\delta>0$, so that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt \epsilon$ for all $|x-x_0|\lt\delta$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
If we choose δ = ϵ/K, would that give us the right solution?

Comment: @JoeS Yes it will!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm just curious to know why the question gave, as a hint, to use the squeeze law? Is there another way to solve this question which involves both the squeeze law AND the ϵ-δ definition?

Comment: @JoeS: I don't see a solution using both squeeze and $\epsilon-\delta$. Is either  the squeeze ($\color{red}{0}\leq \left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|\leq\color{red}{K\left|x-x_0\right|}$) or the $\epsilon-\delta$.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Thanks for all of your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: I was looking over this question and I noticed that when you gave an answer, it didn't include $$0<|x−x_0|<δ$$ but rather only $$|x−x_0|<δ$$. Do you think you could explain this? thanks

Comment: @JoeS To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_definition_.28epsilon-delta.29_of_continuous_functions): "continuity of $f:I\to\mathbb R$ at $c\in I$ means that for every $\epsilon\gt0$ there exists a $\delta\gt0$ such that for all $x\in I$:$$|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon."$$So for the continuity it's enough (actually it's equivalent) to show that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ if $|x-x_0|\lt\delta$.

Comment: Okay, thankyou very much for your help.